# Is there any logical relation between different types of UML diagrams?

Tags: uml

I'm trying to find out ,that is there any relation between different types of UML diagrams, for example, once you developed a use case, should it be an event for each of them in a sequence diagram, or is there any exact relation between the use case and class diagrams.

By the way my main focus is on the below diagrams:

- Use case
- class diagram
- activity
- sequence
- event

if you think I need any extra diagram to be included so it can be used to connecting the above diagrams to each other, please mention it too.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very common to have a sequence diagram for each a use case. In fact activity & sequence diagram can be both used to describe a process but in a different way (I prefer the sequence diagram).

I didn't use class diagram in UML much because I think this is something the developer must design himself. When we describe a system in UML, the difficulty is to be as much high level as possible but also as precise as possible. Class diagram is too precise.

I used Enterprise Architect extensively in the past (in fact I don't use it anymore because I stopped using UML completely) and it provides a very nice interface to link between different diagrams and components. I'm sure you'll find more information in its [documentation](http://www.sparxsystems.com/uml_tool_guide/).

Comment: I'm downloading its trial version right now, and about to working with it, actually what I'm working on is to finding the shortest formula that enables developers to tracing a requirement (functional) from its written statement throughout the diagrams I've mentioned above by priority 1-use case 2-event 3-activity 4-sequence 5-class to the code.since the program is new for me , is what I said, what the program does? ( so i can just find the formula it use ) or no its a different thing?

Comment: If you are serious about doing UML, please pick a *light* version of it. Look for *ICONIX* and this book: **Agile Development with ICONIX Process: People, Process, and Pragmatism**.

Comment: I just checked wiki , seems like what I exactly need, that was a great suggestion, thanks a lot.